# SwiftUI Timer restart after canceling

Tags: timer, swiftui, restart

I'm still trying out timers and this works as well. The timer is exited after a certain time. But how can I restart it now? I'm grateful for any help. I suspect with .autoconnect (). But I don't really get it.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var timerHold = false
    @State var waitingTimerCount = 0
    let waiting = ["A","B","C",]
    let waitingTimer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.timerHold = true
                 }) { Text("Button") }

        if timerHold == true {
            Text(verbatim: waiting[waitingTimerCount])
                .onReceive(waitingTimer) { timer in
                    self.waitingTimerCount = (self.waitingTimerCount + 1) % self.waiting.count
                        if self.waitingTimerCount == 3 {
                            self.timerHold = false
                            self.waitingTimerCount = 0
                            self.waitingTimer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
}

//??
// self.waitingTimer.upstream.autoconnect()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

auto-connecting timer in playground

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import Combine
import Foundation
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
// start automatically
cancellable = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .default)
    .autoconnect()
    .sink {
        print($0)
    }
```

prints

```
...
2020-02-24 02:22:20 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:21 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:22 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:23 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:24 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:25 +0000
2020-02-24 02:22:26 +0000
...
```

manually start / stop timer

```
let timerPublisher = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: RunLoop.main, in: .default)
cancellable = timerPublisher
    .sink {
        print($0)
    }

/// ...

// start publishing time
let cancellableTimerPublisher = timerPublisher.connect()
// stop publishing time
cancellableTimerPublisher.cancel()
```

Comment: How can I implement this in my project? Would like to do it via self.waitingTimer.upstream.autoconnect (), is that not possible?

Comment: @dankell autoconnect is oprerator applied on publisher (as you see in the examples), like any of others operators like .map, .flatMap ... Yes, the publisher has to support it. (as in the examples). use connect / cancel if you like to do it "manually"

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this solution don't allow us to restart the Timer

Comment: restart is not working with this approach

Comment: @MarcT.  please check apple documentation. Timer is not reusable. Swift’s Timer class allows us to schedule work. Repeat the work or run it once.